# How do I get parent name with arrow on recursive select option

Tags: php, recursion

I have multiple same name in child column. In `Men have Shoes` & `Women have Shoes`

```
function makeSelect ($items, $depth = 0) 
{    
    $result = '';

    foreach ( $items as $item ) 
    {
        $result .= '<option value="' . $item['id'] . '">';
        $result .= str_repeat('->', $depth);
        $result .= $item['name'] . '</option>';

        if ( array_key_exists('children', $item) ) 
            $result .= makeSelect($item['children'], $depth+1);
    }

    return $result;
}
```

The function working fine. Sometime confusing me to select a valid category.

How do I get the option including parent name & arrow?

Example :

```
<option value="1">Women</option>
<option value="2">Women->Shoes</option>
<option value="2">Women->Shoes->Boots</option>
```

Update : [**content**](http://pastebin.com/3tePVhpX) of `$items`

Comment: Could you post the contents of `$items`?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/3tePVhpX for the array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here what I've done.

```
function makeSelect($items, $parent = null) 
{
    $result = '';

    foreach ( $items as $key => $item )
    {
        $result .= '<option value="'.$key.'">'.$parent.$item['name'].'</option>';
        if (array_key_exists('children', $item)) 
            $result .= makeSelect($item['children'],$parent . $item['name']." -> ");
    }
    return $result;
}
```